# swiftui ObservedObject function call in all view

Tags: swiftui

I've a problem with my code, I've two View, in the second View I've an a ObservedObject like this,

```
struct SecondView: View {

    @ObservedObject var lineup = TestViewModel()

    var body: some View {}
}
```

The TestViewModel is a Class like this,

```
final class TestViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        test()
    }
    @Published var lineup = Test().self
    private func test() {
        Webservices().getData() {
          self.lineup = $0
        }
    }
}
```

The TestViewModel get data from server.
The problem is that the function is call when build start and in every view and not only in the SecondView. 
Thanks!!

Comment: It sounds like what you meant to do was make this a shared Environment variable.

Comment: I don't get it, when do you want the methid test() to be called? could you show us the first view as well

Comment: test() is call from init() so when call var lineup = TestViewModel()

Comment: Any news with this? I have the same problem